# After successfully login in facebook, i show this notification:

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEh3N.png)

I tried to dismiss it by code#1:

```
webdriver.Chrome('F:/chromedriver_win32 (3)/chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=options)
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
```

This code doesn't work for me.

I also tried with the code#2:

```
alert=driver.switch_to_alert()
alert.dismiss()
```

Can anyone help me to solve this out ?

Comment: You’re not supposed to log in using any such automation in the first place, that is against Facebook ToS.

Comment: Ohhh....I didn't know that...I'll be taking care for this next time....Thanks....!!!

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have chosen the right argument **`--disable-notifications`** but have placed it in a wrong sequence. But definitely it's not an **`Alert`**. Here is your own code block with a simple change:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
```

Answer (score 0):

don't have knowledge of python too much, but you have to use ChromeOptions before set properties of chromedriver. Also it is not an alerts these are notifications In java you can use like this:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","path to driver");
WebDriver driver =new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
```